# Extracting parts of filename

Tags: bash, shell, filenames

I'm trying to use a part of the file name to be inserted into a new file created using the script. For eg:
`dcn_2014_01_31_14_17_45_505.pcap` and
`dcn_2014_01_31_14_32_27_656.pcap`  should give
`2014_0131_1417_to_1432_utc.pcap`. I can get it up to `dcn_2014_01_31_14_17_45_505_to_dcn_2014_01_31_14_32_27_656.pcap` . How do I select each number so as to get the desired output?
I have used the following script:

```
TAG1=$(basename ${FILES[0]} | sed 's/.pcap//')
TAG2=$(basename ${FILES[$N-1]} | sed 's/.pcap//')

#merge the files
mergecap -w /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/"${TAG1}_to_${TAG2}".pcap ${FILES[@]}
```

Where FILES[] is an array of 15 files.

Comment: Could you use simpler file name examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For modern versions of `bash`, you can use an array to store the different parts of the filename. Something like:

```
TAG1=( $(basename "${FILES[0]}" | sed 's/_/ /g') )
TAG2=( $(basename "${FILES[$N-1]}" | sed 's/_/ /g') )

range="${TAG1[1]}_${TAG1[2]}${TAG1[3]}_${TAG1[4]}${TAG1[5]}_to_${TAG2[4]}${TAG2[5]}"

echo "$range"
#mergecap -w /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/"$range"_utc.pcap ${FILES[@]}
```

You can also use bash to get the basename and do the substitution:

```
TAG1="${FILES[0]##*/}"
TAG1=( ${TAG1//_/ } )
TAG2="${FILES[$N-1]##*/}"
TAG2=( ${TAG2//_/ } )
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is easier to do with Perl's regex and captures:

```
$filename =~ /dcn_(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{2}).*\.pcap/;
my $year = $1;
my $month = $2;
my $day = $3;
my $hour = $4;
my $minute = $5;
```

Then you just do the same for the other file and format the output filename however you want.